# Inject Immutable ConfigurationProperties in Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the follwing Configuration Properites defined:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "keycloak")
@ConstructorBinding
@Getter
@Setter
public class KeycloakConfigurationProperties {
  @NotBlank
  private final String authServerUrl;
  @NotBlank
  private final String realm;
  @NotBlank
  private final String clientId;
  @NotBlank
  private final String clientSecret;

  public KeycloakConfigurationProperties(String authServerUrl, String realm,
      String clientId, String clientSecret) {
    this.authServerUrl = authServerUrl;
    this.realm = realm;
    this.clientId = clientId;
    this.clientSecret = clientSecret;
  }
}
```

And it is configured for my test like this

```yaml
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8081/auth
  realm: master
  client-id: foo-service
  client-secret: 2f217834-1c44-4c2f-a0f1-19ff0d0bd73d
```

Now when I'm trying to Inject the ConfigurationProperties in my Test class, I get the follwing exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'keycloakConfigurationProperties': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.lang.String' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

My test looks like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Keycloak.class, KeycloakConfigurationProperties.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class KeycloakTest {

  @MockBean
  Keycloak keycloak;

  @Autowired
  KeycloakConfigurationProperties keycloakConfigurationProperties;
}
```

How can I inject the ConfigurationProperties in my test?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `KeycloakConfigurationProperties` class is in the same package as your `SpringBootApplication` class and your `KeycloakTest` class, change `@EnableConfigurationProperties` in your `KeycloakTest` to `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan`. If they are in different package pass it as argument in `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` e.g. `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.example.configurationpropertiespackage")`.

I would also remove `(classes = { Keycloak.class, KeycloakConfigurationProperties.class })` from `@SpringBootTest` unless you have some specific reason to have it.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
class KeycloakTest {

...
}
```